# insert a date in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, parsing

I use a jquery datepicker then i read it in my servlet like that:

String dateimput=request.getParameter("datepicker");//1
then parse it like that:

```
System.out.println("datepicker:" +dateimput);  
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");               
    java.util.Date dt = null;
    try
    {
        dt = df.parse(dateimput);
        System.out.println("date imput parssé1 est:" +dt);
        System.out.println("date imput parsée2 est:" +df.format(dt));

    } catch (ParseException e)
   {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and insert query like that:

```
String query = "Insert into dailytimesheet(trackingDate,activity,projectCode) values ("+df.format(dt)+", \""+activity+"\" ,\""+projet+"\")";
```

it pass successfully untill now but if i check the record inserted i found the date:
01/01/0001 00:00:00

l've tried to fix it but it still a mess for me.

Comment: What does "query" look like before you send/apply in mysql? Show us what you're inserting

Comment: datepicker:04/30/2010
date imput parssé1 est:Fri Apr 30 00:00:00 CEST 2010
date imput parsée2 est:04/30/2010

Comment: Unless you want SQL injections to occur, one should use `PreparedStatement` to place values into a SQL statement rather than using string concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the Date in the format: "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: @kawtousse but it is answer to your noob question and worth at least upvoting

Comment: And yes, I totally agree with Guillaume that you SHOULD USE PreparedStatements for security and readability reasons!

Answer (score 4):

Use [`PreparedStatements`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), they have a setDate(...) method.

Seriously, **please use PreparedStatements**! especially in a webapp context. You'll be facing [SQL injections](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injection_SQL) otherwise