# How to insert current date in database mysql

Tags: php, mysql

hello i am using insert query with a different pattern so i just want to 
insert the current date in database but i can't find a place to put $date in insert query

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date)));    

$sql="INSERT INTO `delivery`(product_id,pr_name,pr_price,pr_size,user_id)
         SELECT  `product_id`,`pr_name`,`pr_price`,`pr_size`, `userid`  
         FROM `shopping_cart` WHERE `userid` = $uid";
```

Comment: create or find date column in your table and pass $date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [insert a date in mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736830/insert-a-date-in-mysql-database)

Comment: @rocky i've already created the date column but how can i add this through a query which i've explained up there

Comment: @Talhiner post value of $date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not pass date or datetime from PHP if you want the date/datetime at the time of yours query's execution, instead you can use built-in MySQL functions to do so

To insert current date & time use `NOW()`

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `delivery`(product_id,pr_name,pr_price,pr_size,user_id, dt)
    SELECT  `product_id`,`pr_name`,`pr_price`,`pr_size`,
        `userid`, NOW()  
    FROM `shopping_cart` WHERE `userid` = $uid";
```

To insert current date only use `CURRENT_DATE()`

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `delivery`(product_id,pr_name,pr_price,pr_size,user_id, dt)
    SELECT  `product_id`,`pr_name`,`pr_price`,`pr_size`,
        `userid`, CURRENT_DATE()  
    FROM `shopping_cart` WHERE `userid` = $uid";
```

These queries assume you have a column named `dt` in your `delivery` table. Please change column name if different in your schema, or add a `date` or `datetime` column in your table if you do not have any yet

Comment: Didnt I already say this 8 minutes ago? `NOW()` is just fine regardless of the column format. MySQL will work it all out

Comment: Yeah that's the same thing i was just trying to do and it has been solved thanks for the help. I really appreciate your help and quick reply..

Comment: @RiggsFolly, using `NOW()` for a `date` will generate a *Data truncated for column 'dt' at row 1* warning. CURRENT_DATE() will not

Comment: It will, but who will notice?

Comment: Yes I did, see the inner select after `userid, NOW()`

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to do the date capture in PHP, as long as you want the date to be the date as at time of execution of the query. You can use the MySQL `NOW()` function, just add it to the inner query in the correct column to match the outer queries columns.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `delivery` (product_id,pr_name,pr_price,pr_size,user_id, PR_DATE)
     SELECT  `product_id`,`pr_name`,`pr_price`,`pr_size`, `userid`, NOW()
     FROM `shopping_cart` WHERE `userid` = $uid";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert your own date then use as per below-

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date)));    

$sql="INSERT INTO `delivery`(product_id,pr_name,pr_price,pr_size,user_id, your_date_column)
         SELECT  `product_id`,`pr_name`,`pr_price`,`pr_size`,
                 `userid`, '$date' 
         FROM `shopping_cart` WHERE `userid` = $uid";
```

If you want to put current date then use as per below-

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `delivery`(product_id,pr_name,pr_price,pr_size,user_id, your_date_column)
         SELECT  `product_id`,`pr_name`,`pr_price`,`pr_size`,
                 `userid`, CURDATE()  
         FROM `shopping_cart` WHERE `userid` = $uid";
```

Note: If you want to insert with time then use now().

Comment: Didn't @mynawaz say exactly this 9 minutes before?

Comment: you should wrap `$date` in apostrophes like `'$date'`

Answer (score 1):

I cant understand your clearly. Normally, we insert current date like

- curdate()
- sysdate()

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer

Answer (score 1):

Use now() in your query to get the current date.

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer

Answer (score 1):

First of you have to check whether you have column for current date  or not in your database table. If not then you have to add a column to store current date and use that column in your query.

You can use timestamp /datetime / now() function to store current date(choose one according to your  requirement)

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `delivery` (product_id,pr_name,pr_price,pr_size,user_id, curr_date)
 SELECT  `product_id`,`pr_name`,`pr_price`,`pr_size`,
         `userid`, timestamp
 FROM `shopping_cart` WHERE `userid` = $uid";
```

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer